# Reference multiple column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server procedure returning me this kind of output:

```
ID   | Name   | Value
100  | Name1  | COUNT([104])
101  | Name2  | ADD([100],[102])
102  | Name3  | SELECT([100])
104  | Name4  | SUB([100],[101],[102])
```

I want to resolve the strings contained in the Value to their respective Name column values such that the output is as follows:

```
ID   | Name   | Value
100  | Name1  | COUNT([Name4])
101  | Name2  | ADD([Name1],[Name3])
102  | Name3  | SELECT([Name1])
104  | Name4  | SUB([Name1],[Name2],[Name3])
```

Essentially, I need to replace all the IDs within the square brackets [] in the Value column, with their actual Name values.

How should I go about in achieving this output?

Comment: How is your data actually stored? If it is stored in a normal form and the stored procedure is denormalising it then it will probably be better to query the raw data rather than work with the output of the procedure.

Comment: Can you post your procedure? Also, what are you trying to do with this value? If you are going to execute it, it may be better to do that directly.

Comment: good questions indeed. if you really need to do this like you mentioned, you can check out my answer.

Comment: The contents of ID, Name and Value columns are being pulled from various tables via joins and are not stored in one single table. I do not intend to do anything with these values explicitly. Nor do I care about performance issues.

Comment: I am doing a SELECT of these columns in the procedure. Is it possible to call some function from there sending this Value's value and in the other function resolve the ID with the Name in the value from (Table 1). The ID and Name does exist together in a single table (Table 1) and the Value is referenced to give this output using multiple joins.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I go about in achieving this output?

If you really need to do this, this will result in a quite ugly function, which parses the number of the string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

Then your query will look like this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, REPLACE(Value, dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Value), NAME)
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to communicate. When I call a REPLACE function, does all the occurences of the regex at [] get replaced or just the first one?

Comment: I would like the values inside [] be replaced by the Name values. The ID and Name exist on one single table, so I can do a SELECT query there. However the Value is returned via multiple joins. So I am passing the Value to the FUNCTION and want the value that is returned to be replaced by the Name which I extract from the first Table based on the same ID.

Comment: @Rg90 This should be exactly what you are looking for, based on your descriptions.

Comment: Yes, I would like to store the result of the stored procedure into a temp table, so that it becomes easy for me to do this transformation and also keep the SP intact. Would you recommend it? I'm not really concerned with the performance to get this output.

Comment: Either that, or if you dont need the old values, you can also update the current table.
I don't know your exact context (situation, problems, etc.) to decide if I recommended this. ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't update the current table, as there are internal queries done on that. Making an update to this one, would trigger other repercussions. I will try giving it a shot by pushing it into a temp table and see what I can do with it.

Comment: When I invoke the function I face this issue:

Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.udf_GetNumeric", or the name is ambiguous.

How can I invoke a function from the SELECT query?

Comment: @Rg90 Actually my function only works for one argument (e.g. COUNT[..])

Comment: I see. Thanks for your extended help :) I'll try creating a function that would yield me this result.

Comment: Exactly, that would be the way to go.